# margins for Twenty Twelve theme

Tags: css, wordpress

Digging through Style.css theme, I coulnd find how to change 2 kinds of margins:

1. Margin between browser border and site page
2. Margin between site page border and site content.

I did it for my website http://raigle.net. See Margin 1 and Margin 2 on the picture:

[image]

I'm not a pro in Wordpress styling and would be glad to any advice!

Comment: There is no margin there, but padding. Use the inspector from chrome to play around first amd see what you don't understand then you can try post your code here.

Comment: Thanks, have to pay more attention how to work with the Inspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about margin1:

it is not margin, it is padding:

```
.ui-content {
border-width: 0;
overflow: visible;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding: 15px;  /*  change here  */
}
```

about margin2:

it is not margin too, it is padding:

```
.site {
padding: 0 24px;  /*  change here  */
padding: 0 1.714285714rem;  /*  change here  */
background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When looking for styling, you can use Chrome's Inspector.

Right click an element > Inspect element. It looks like you have an element that acts as an overlay. Just delete (select in elements panel then hit delete) the node and try again.

It's pretty nifty.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3tGS.png

Comment: Yeah, that would help me figure out the correct classes: ui-content and .site and their padding properties.

Answer (score 0):

1. http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css - line 12 - change padding style for .ui-content {
2. in http://raigle.net/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/style.css,wp-content/plugins/easy-fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.6.pack.css

   - you have to change padding for div.site. You probably need to add !important clausule for this one, as this style is overwritten in couple other files

Comment: Thank you for pointing out files and especially !important property. Now I can fine-tune the site for mobile devices.